# How do I scan android internal memory for viruses?

Tags: internal-sd

1. First I want to make sure can windows threats and viruses get into android internal storage when connected to PC?
2. If yes, How to scan internal storage in PC with windows antivirus? because USB connection is not "Mass Storage" and unable to right click and scan.
3. I usually use apps like Telegram and retrieve photos, videos and documents (all file types) to my android memory. are these files can be infected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if a virus is programmed with the intention to spread widely to other devices, it certainly can copy itself to any connected media.
2. A *good* antivirus can scan MTP devices (like your phone) and spot a potential virus (at least my AV does).
3. It depends on the virus itself.
   In the worst case, if you have a rooted device, debugging mode activated and allowed *adb* to connect without asking, a virus *could* infect your private applications data.
   In the, more or less, best case it could only steal or destroy photos, videos, documents etc, but *no messages* from apps like Telegram.

Comment: Keep in mind: it doesn't matter how you scan for viruses affecting Android, they won't be found (there are none). But of course any storage can be used as "means of transport".